# Find the integral of $\int{\frac{e^{3x}+1}{e^x+1}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find: $$\int{\frac{e^{3x}+1}{e^x+1}dx}$$
Here's my wrong solution:
$$t=e^x, t'=e^x=t, dx=t'dt=tdt$$
$$\int\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}tdt=\int\frac{t^4+t}{t+1}dt$$
Through polynomial division:
$$\int\frac{t^4+t}{t+1}dt = \int (t^3-t^2+t)dt=\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^2}{2}+C=\frac{3t^4-4t^3+6t^2}{12}+C$$
Revert $t$ back to $e^x$:
$$\frac{3e^{4x}-4e^{3x}+6e^{2x}}{12}+C$$
... Which is wrong because the derivative of that expression is:
$$e^{4x}-e^{3x}+e^{2x}$$

Where's my mistake?

Comment: $dx\ne t\,dt$ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your substitution computation is wrong. It is $dt=t'dx=tdx$ or $dx=dt/t$ which you would also get from $x=\ln(t)$.

---

But in the end, you can apply polynomial division already to the original expression
$$
\frac{e^{3x}+1}{e^x+1}=e^{2x}-e^x+1
$$
which is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Expanding the integrand gives:

$$=\int\frac{e^{3x}}{e^x+1}dx+\int\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

Set $t=e^x$ and $dt=e^xdx$

$$=\int\frac{t^2}{t+1}dt+\int\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

Long division:

$$\int\frac{dt}{t+1}+\int t dt-\int1dt+\int\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

$$=-t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\ln|t+1|+\int\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

Set $\nu=e^x$ and $d\nu=e^xdx$

$$=-t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\ln|t+1|+\int\frac{d\nu}{\nu(\nu+1)}$$

Partial fractions:

$$=-t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\ln|t+1|+\int\frac{d\nu}{\nu}-\int\frac{d\nu}{\nu+1}=\dots$$

I will let you finish